# Poor Animation FBX Export, Random Rotations of Bones

Tags: animation, armature, export, unity, .fbx

I created some animations(like idle, walk, attack etc.) for a model in blender. I then exported them as an fbx to use them in unity. All the animations works fine in blender. In unity, all of them work except the last one, which is rotated quickly and then returns back to normal in like 4 frames. When reimporting the fbx in blender, the animation had the same issue, but only that one. What can I do? (first picture is the original blender project, second is unity, third is reimporting the fbx on blender, all of them show frame 5 of the animation).[image]

[image]

[image]